# Induction proof that if $P(A_1)=P(A_2)= \cdots =P(A_n)=1$ then $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap\cdots \cap A_n)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Show that, If $P(A_1)=P(A_2)= \cdots =P(A_n)=1$ then $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap\cdots \cap A_n)=1$

I tried to do this by induction, but it does not work out: I know that $P(A_1)=P(A_2)=1$  so  $P(A_1 \cap A_2)=1$

Does anybody have any tips of how to prove this?

Comment: Think about it this way. $A_i$ represents a possible event in a certain scenario, and the possibility of such an event is 1, or 100%. If every event $A_1$...$A_n$ has a 100% probability of happening, all events must be happening together, since all are certain to happen. So $P(A_1 \cap...  A_n)=1$. Use that idea to help with your proof by induction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you know that $P(A_1)=P(A_2)=1\Rightarrow P(A_1\cap A_2)=1$

(*which is a straightforward result.  $P(A_1)=1$ implies that $A_1$ is an almost sure event, similarly for $A_2$, and an almost sure event intersected with another is still an almost sure event*)

Lets look at the next step:  Lets call $A_1\cap A_2$ something else for the moment, lets say $B_2 = A_1\cap A_2$.  Using the same logic as before, we have $P(B_2)=P(A_3)=1$ so $P(B_2\cap A_3)=1$.  Remembering what "$B_2$" was though, that means $P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)=1$

Base case: $n=2$, we have $P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^2 A_i)=1$

Suppose for our induction hypothesis that if $P(A_1)=P(A_2)=\dots=P(A_k)=1$ then $P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^k A_i)=1$ for some $k\geq 2$.  We wish now to prove that it follows for $k+1$ as well.

Note: $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} A_i = \left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^k A_i\right)\cap A_{k+1}$.  Use your induction hypothesis on $P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{k} A_i)$ and reach the conclusion.

Comment: I don't think it is correct to say that $P(A_1)=1$ implies that $A_1$ is the _sure_ event; it is merely an event of probability $1$. For example, if $X$ is a continuous random variable, say a standard normal random variable, then $P(X\neq 1) = 1$, but $(X \neq 1)$ is _not_ the sure event.

Comment: @Dilip fair enough.  Instead of the sure event then, I suppose it would be better to refer to it as an *almost sure* event.  Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $P(B_1) = 0$ and $P(B_2) = 0$, then $P(B_1\cup B_2) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are events then :
$$p(X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \cdots \cup X_n) \leq p(X_1) + p(X_2) + \cdots + p(X_n)$$
We have :
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
p(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) & = & 1 - p(\overline{A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n}) \\[3mm]
& = & 1 - p(\overline{A_1} \cup \overline{A_2} \cup \cdots \cup \overline{A_n}) \\[3mm]
& \geq & 1 - (p(\overline{A_1}) + p(\overline{A_2}) + \cdots + p(\overline{A_n})) \\[3mm]
& \geq & 1 - (1 - p(A_1)) + (1 - p(A_2)) + \cdots + (1 - p(A_n)) \\[3mm]
& = & 1 - (1 - 1) + (1 - 1) + \cdots + (1 - 1) \\[3mm]
& = & 1
\end{array}$$
then :
$$1 \leq p(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) \leq 1$$
Hence :
$$p(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) = 1$$